# JavaFX - How to style the application window like Excel/Word 2016 (Flat windows)

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am developing a JavaFX application and would like to have a flat window similar to Skype/Word 2016/Excel 2016.

I see there are styles to make the stage background transparent or minimal but could not find for a flat type panel. How can i do that?

Comment: you mean `Stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: No.. I want the stage style like windows 10. https://www.thurrott.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/apps-folder.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want exactly but maybe this is worth having a look at. [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix)

Comment: Thank you!! I think i can use JFoenix for elements inside the application.. I am also looking for windows 10 style like application - https://www.thurrott.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/apps-folder.jpg . I am using windows 7 and the style of the window is default.